# Playa inside Matrix with MSM

Tags: matrix, playa, multi-site-manager

We're seeing a bit of strange behavior - perhaps our eyes are missing the obvious thing?

This block of code works correctly when used in a template in the main or default site in a MSM configuration.  It also partially works on templates in the added-on site (which happens to be a mobile version of the site: m.domain.com).  Our problem is that the deepest loop using the playa field menu-section-items is not displaying any of the children.

For clarity:

menu-sections = Matrix Field
menu-section-title = Matrix Cell/Column type text
menu-section-items = Matrix Cell/Column type Playa

We have attempted this with real values substituted for the segment variables to no avail. Either method works when used in templates in the default site.

CODE:

```
  {exp:channel:entries site="default_site" channel="menu" url_title="{segment_3}"}

     {menu-sections row_id="{segment_4}"}

        {menu-section-title}    

        {menu-section-items} {if no_children} -flag- {/if}

             <li>
                <span class="menu_item_title">{menu-item-title}</span>
                <span class="menu_item_desc">{menu-item-description}</span>
             </li>

        {/menu-section-items}

     {/menu-sections}

   {/exp:channel:entries}
```

One strange bit of info we uncovered while testing is that the conditional check for children above immediately after the opening menu-section-items tag renders the -flag- contents ONLY when there ARE actual relationships. If relationships are simply blank this -flag- text will not render.  Very odd...

In troubleshooting this problem we have updated our Expression Engine to version 2.7.2 - Build Date: 20131008.  (Current)
Matrix 2.5.8 (Current)
Playa 4.4.5 (Current)

I hope someone can point us in another direction or highlight an error above?

Thanks!

David

Comment: {exp:playa:children site="default_site" field="menu-section-items" status="not closed"}
{title}
{/exp:playa:children}

Comment: same result as the first syntax method

Comment: David, first off - rewrite the template using the var_prefix parameter, so that the template becomes a bit more readable and you eliminate naming conflicts. For an example on how that parameter works, take a look at http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/children.html and do a search for "var_prefix". Let's see where that gets us.